# InvalidArgumentError: Data too short when trying to read string [[{{node DecodeWav}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Tags: tensorflow, audio, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

I've been trying to learn audio classification with the tensorflow implementation but I am running into an error when I am testing it on another dataset.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob("C:/Users/Natha/Downloads/voice_emotions/audio_speech_actors_01-24/*/*")
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)

print("Number of files: ", len(filenames))
print("Sample file: ", filenames[0])

train_files = filenames[:1200]
val_files = filenames[1200:1300]
test_files = filenames[1300:]

def decode_audio(audio_binary):
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
    return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)

def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, "-")
    return parts[-4]

def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
    return waveform, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

rows = 3
cols = 3
n = rows * cols
fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 12))
for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds.take(n)):
    r = i // cols
    c = i % cols
    ax = axes[r][c]
    ax.plot(audio.numpy())
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, 0.2))
    label = label.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    ax.set_title(label)
    
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-8a7064627ebf> in <module>
      3 n = rows * cols
      4 fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 12))
----> 5 for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds.take(n)):
      6     r = i // cols
      7     c = i % cols

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    759   def __next__(self):
    760     try:
--> 761       return self._next_internal()
    762     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    763       raise StopIteration

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    742     # to communicate that there is no more data to iterate over.
    743     with context.execution_mode(context.SYNC):
--> 744       ret = gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next(
    745           self._iterator_resource,
    746           output_types=self._flat_output_types,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py in iterator_get_next(iterator, output_types, output_shapes, name)
   2725       return _result
   2726     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 2727       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   2728     except _core._FallbackException:
   2729       pass

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6939   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6940   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6941   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6942   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6943 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Data too short when trying to read string
     [[{{node DecodeWav}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

I've made sure that all items in the dataset are all the right size but the error might still be the dataset. I've seen many other people get this error but none of their solutions helped.

Versions:
Tensorflow: 2.6.0
Dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/uwrfkaggler/ravdess-emotional-speech-audio

Comment: Update 2: While I have put audio deep learning to the side, I am still hoping for a better solution for this problem. Has anyone made any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I was able to find a workaround for the problem. I found the valid and corrupted files using this code.

```
corrupted_files = []
valid_files = []
wave = iter(waveform_ds)

for i in range(1440):
    try:
        for index, tensor in enumerate(wave.get_next()):
            valid_files.append(filenames[i])
    except:
        corrupted_files.append(filenames[i])
```

Unfortunately, most of my files were corrupted so hopefully there is a way to get rid of this issue instead of avoiding it.